# Accidentally deleted the entire hard drive during Ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I tried to install Ubuntu 23.04 on my device which was running on Windows 10. During the installation I might have selected the *Erase all data and install Ubuntu* option and got my full HDD erased along with Windows 10. I had my whole life's photo backup there. They need to be recovered somehow.

1. I tried testdisk but the listing does not show any sign of my files. Maybe I am using the testdisk in the wrong way.
2. Used the data recovery option in GParted, but it was not able to detect the filesystem at all.

Current partitions:

[image: Partitions]

Partition table:

[image: table]

Comment: Restore the backup you made of your personal data. Otherwise you are not likely to get your data back; recovery software depends on a SINGLE write. Installing Ubuntu does more than 1 write.

Comment: The question you're asking has nothing to do with Ubuntu - sorry. What you're asking is to restore your data from a formatted harddisk - either from backup or data forensics. This community can't help with that.

Comment: If the lost data is valuable to you, then you should seek professional data recovery assistance. It may be expensive...that's the (literal) price of valuable data that is not backed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)